# How to check if array item matches array item in liquid (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

Can anyone help me finish my code here? I'm trying to filter search results by only showing products tagged with a tag that matches customer tags.

For example, a customer (tagged with "Mustang") searches Ford on the front end.
(Normally - all Ford products would be displayed.)
However, If the customer is tagged Mustang, only products tagged Mustang would display.

Here's what I have so far; the results aren't empty, but they do not display.

```html
{% for item in search.results %}
    {% if item.object_type == 'product' %}
 
        <!-- for tag in product tags do -->
        {% for tag in product.tags %}
 
            <!-- If tag in product tags do -->
            {% if tag contains customer.tags %}
                {% assign product = item %}
                {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
            {% endif %}
 
        {% endfor %} 

    {% else %}
        <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-third small--one-half">
            <h2 class="h3">{{ item.title | link_to: item.url }}</h2>
            <p>{{ item.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `product.tags` in the search result, it should be `item.tags`

```
{% for item in search.results %}
    {% if item.object_type == 'product' %}

        <!-- for tag in product tags do -->
        {% for tag in item.tags %}
 
            <!-- If tag in product tags do -->
            {% if customer.tags contains tag %}
                {% assign product = item %}
                {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
            {% endif %}
 
        {% endfor %} 

    {% else %}
        <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-third small--one-half">
            <h2 class="h3">{{ item.title | link_to: item.url }}</h2>
            <p>{{ item.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice catch didn't see that one. +1

Comment: You sir, are a legend.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code is correct except one part `{% if tag contains customer.tags %}` this should be the other way around, like so:

```
{% if customer.tags contains tag %}
```

You want to check if the `customer.tags` contains a specific tag and not that the tag contains the custom tags.

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input bud. Sadly even with your suggestion, I'm still getting a blank page. I can see the results dumped in the console so I know the results are being returned, just not displayed as intended. (At all)

Comment: @Beaniie are you sure that the search items includes at least one product with that tag? If you haven't overwritten the pagination it returns a set number of products and not all results on a single request and it's possible to get empty response since it never enters the if statement. I mean if none of the first 20 (or 50 don't remember the default pagination for the search) include the customer tag it won't show a product.

Comment: Checking the product tags in the dump, and the searched keyword, all expected items have been retrieved 6. total pagination is set to 12, and the product tags match the customer tags letter for letter, inc case.

Comment: @Beaniie well then I don't know. Check if it enters the if statement, if it goes there the issue is with your snippet, if doesn't enter and you are sure that the current returned products has the customer tag then the issue is somewhere else. The only other issue I see is that if the product has multiply tags of that customer it will be outputted more than once and you may want to add a `{% break %}` statement there, but I don't see anything other that can prevent you to show the products.